# Surface Integral formed by Paraboloid of revolution and Cylinder

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> Compute the integral $\iint_S (y^2z dxdy+xzdydz+x^2ydxdz)$ where S is the outer side of the surfaces situated in the first octant and formed by the paraboloid of revolution $z=x^2+y^2, $ cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the coordinate planes

**My attempt:-**
$F=<xz,x^2y,y^2z>, \vec n = \frac{2x \vec i+2y \vec j- \vec k}{\sqrt{4(x^2+y^2)+1}}\\ \vec F \cdot \vec n = \frac {2 x^2z+2x^2y^2-y^2z}{\sqrt{4(x^2+y^2)+1}} \\ \iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n dS \\ = \iint \frac {2 x^2z+2x^2y^2-y^2z}{\sqrt{4(x^2+y^2)+1}} dS$

Taking $\vec R = (r \cos \theta, r  \sin \theta, r^2) \\\vec R_r = (\cos \theta, \sin  \theta, 2r) \\\vec R_{\theta} = (-r \sin  \theta,r \cos  \theta, 0) \\  \vec R_r \times \vec R_{ \theta}  = \vec i(-2r^2 \cos  \theta ) - \vec j (2r^2 \sin  \theta) + \vec k (r) \\ |\vec R_r \times \vec R_{ \theta}  | = r \sqrt{4r^2+1}$

$\iint_S \vec F \cdot \vec n dS =  \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} \int_{r=0}^1 (2r^5 \cos^2 \theta+2r^5 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta - r^5 \sin^2 \theta) dr d \theta = \fbox {$\frac{\pi}{16}$}$

But given answer is $\fbox {$\frac{\pi}{8}$}$

I used **gauss divergence theorem**, i am getting $\fbox {$\frac{\pi}{8}$}$

Pls tell me where i went wrong.

Comment: @Nosrati no sir, it is $4r^4(cos^2 \theta + sin^2  \theta)+r^2$

Comment: no problem sir, .....

Comment: Your first integral $\iint_S (y^2z dxdy+xzdydz+x^2ydxdz)$ is the victim of some private notation used by your textbook or teacher. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter i understood sir, below post explains everthing. This is textbook notation. This is exercise problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** I think you droped other surfaces. One may prove for $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ the integrals are zero. The direction of the surface paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ is outer side, that is 
$$\vec n = \color{red}{-}\frac{2x \vec i+2y \vec j- \vec k}{\sqrt{4(x^2+y^2)+1}}$$
also consider cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ with parametrization
$$\vec R = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, z)$$
gives
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^1\left(z \cos ^2(t)+\sin ^2(t) \cos ^2(t)\right)dzdt=\dfrac{3\pi}{16}$$

Comment: Sir now it is perfect. $-(\pi/16)+(3 \pi /16) = (\pi/8)$. I did by gauss divergence theorem. It is straight forward and it is also giving $\pi/8$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good luck $;)$.